# Laptop micro freezes while not on external PSU

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, freeze, battery

Hello I have been having this weird issue

My laptop while not connected to a PSU will experience weird micro freezes where my pc will simply freeze for a few seconds this issue will not accrue in any form while its connected to an external PSU. The battery charge ,CPU and ram usage ,temperature will not affect this issue in any way. I have attempted almost every solution I found online this includes re installing/updating drivers setting up a high performance battery plan, system scans for broken files, I also monitored my CPU usage temperature and nothing seems to be off. I can exclude hardware damage as when I boot windows in safe mode the issue didn't accrue does anyone else have any suggestions on what I could do against this issue ? One weird thing that I discovered was that when I'm using a recording software in this case OBS the issue completely resolves how could OBS affect this issue ?

Comment: Try another battery. Though your current battery (no pun intended) seems OK, since the issue occurs *only* when on battery, that seems likely.

Comment: I can see your logic but it cant be a battery issue I mean considering that the issue will be resolved once OBS is active or windows was booted in safe mode.